# Photo return an 404 error

Tags: foursquare

When I combine the prefix and the suffix of a photo (without the //) (url : https://igx.4sqi.net/img/general/38627358_vvn4Ggz1mRxPDy3sEhLyHvy4ul3F7XqCy5kYxr73uo.jpg), I have an 404 error (I have the data with the Picture API of FourSquare.)
Can you help me ?
P.S : I am French

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your format is incorrect. Read the [photos documentation](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/responses/photo.html) on the correct way to format the photo url. It looks like you're missing a `size` parameter in the URL.

> To assemble a resolvable photo URL, take prefix + size + suffix
>
> size can be one of the following, where XX or YY is one of 36,
>   100,300, or 500.
>
> - XXxYY  original: the original photo's size
> - capXX: cap the photo with a width or height of XX (whichever is larger). Scales the other, smaller dimension proportionally
> - widthXX: forces the width to be XX and scales the height proportionally
> - heightYY: forces the height to    be YY and scales the width proportionally